# Zend_Form Decorators, css and displaygroups

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I'm trying with DisplayGroups in my form. I'm sure it is a css understanding problem.
This is how my form looks like:

[image]

Now I would love to make it nicer:
How can I move the legend of the Displaygroup onto the border?
How can I make the distance smaller between my labels an the fields?

Here is my formclass:

```
$this->setName('Schwestern');
    $this->setMethod('post');

    $vorname=$this->addElement('TextBox','vorname',array(
            'label'     => 'Vorname:',          
    ));

    $nachname=$this->addElement('TextBox','nachname',array(
            'label'     => 'Nachname:', 

    ));

    $strasse=$this->addElement('TextBox','strasse',array(
            'label'     => 'Strasse:',          
    ));

    $plz=$this->addElement('TextBox','plz',array(
            'label'     => 'PLZ:',          
    ));

    $ort=$this->addElement('TextBox','ort',array(
            'label'     => 'Ort:',          
    ));

    $telefon=$this->addElement('TextBox','telefon',array(
            'label'     => 'Telefon:',          
    ));

    $handy=$this->addElement('TextBox','handy',array(
            'label'     => 'Handy:',            
    ));

    $email=$this->addElement('TextBox','email',array(
            'label'     => 'Email:',            
    ));

    $geburtsdatum = $this->addElement('DateTextBox','geburtsdatum',array(
        'label'     => 'Geburtsdatum:',
        'datePattern' => 'dd-MM-yyyy'
    ));



    $this->addDisplayGroup(array(

            'vorname',
            'nachname',
            'strasse',
            'plz',
            'ort',
            'geburtsdatum'

    ),'contact',array('legend' => 'Name und Anschrift'));

    $contact = $this->getDisplayGroup('contact');
    $contact->setDecorators(array(

            'FormElements',
            'Fieldset',
            array('HtmlTag',array('tag'=>'div','style'=>'width:200px;;float:left;border-style:solid; margin:5px;padding:5px;border-width:1px;border-color: grey;'))
    ));

    $this->addDisplayGroup(array('telefon','handy','email'), 'kontaktdaten',array('legend'=>'Kontaktdaten'));
    $this->getDisplayGroup('kontaktdaten')->setDecorators(array(

                'FormElements',
                'Fieldset',
                array('HtmlTag',array('tag'=>'div','style'=>'width:200px;;float:left;border-style:solid; margin:5px;padding:5px;border-width:1px;border-color: grey;'))
    ));


$this->setDecorators(array(
    'FormElements',                       
    array(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'),
    array('tag'=>'table','cellspacing'=>'6')),
    'DijitForm'
));
```

EDIT 22/10/2015:

HTML Output of this part of the form:

[image]

Before I tried to use the fieldsets I decorated my forms like this:

```
$vorname=$this->addElement('TextBox','vorname',array(
            'label'     => 'Vorname:',          
    ));

    $vorname->setDecorators(array(
               'ViewHelper',
               'Description',
               'Errors',
               array(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td')),
               array('Label', array('tag' => 'td')),
               array(array('row'=>'HtmlTag'),array('tag'=>'tr'))
    ));
```

So can I use the decorators, or what would be the best solution to get this form nicer like I described above?

Comment: where is your css? and the generated html of your code?

Comment: I have a css file, but I thought I could solve it with decorators?

Comment: Usually, what I do is I remove DtDdWrapper decorator. I also use HtmlTag to wrap the elements with html tags and set the class if I need to. Maybe you can post the expected html so It would be easier for us to answer your question.

Comment: ok you will get my html and the decorators I use in other forms and my css, very helpful thanks

Comment: thank you for the html but I was hoping you could give us your "expected" html output